# Binding a singleton list to a list view

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, singleton

I'm working on a PoS project and want to have my list view filled with the contents of a singleton list upon opening the window but I cannot get it to fill.

> My singleton class

```
public class Menu
{
    private static Menu instance = new Menu();
    public static Menu GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
    private List<Dish> menu = new List<Dish>();
    public void AddDish(Dish dish)
    {
        menu.Add(dish);
    }

}
```

> XAML for the list view

```
                    <ListView x:Name="lvMenu" Height="191" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Canvas.Left="228" Canvas.Top="12" Width="283">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Dish Name" Width="180" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dish}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Veg" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Vegitarian}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Any help would be much appreciated and I'm happy to post any other code if it is needed

Comment: Just as a side comment. You need to make the Menu default constructor protected or private to be a true singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class accordingly:

```
  public class Menu
  {
    private static Menu instance = new Menu();
    public static Menu GetInstance()
    {
      return instance;
    }
    private List<Dish> menu = new List<Dish>();
    public void AddDish(Dish dish)
    {
      menu.Add(dish);
    }

    public static Menu Instance
    {
      get { return instance; }
    }
    public List<Dish> MenuList
    {
      get { return menu; }
      set { menu = value; }
    }
  }
```

Adding those two Properties `Instance` and `MenuList` allows you to bind them in the XAML.

Add the following declaration to the Window, instead of SingletonBinding should must write the Namespace where your Class Menu is definied:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SingletonBinding"
```

Binding in XAML will look like the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvMenu" Height="191" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Canvas.Left="228" Canvas.Top="12" Width="283" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList, Source={x:Static local:Menu.Instance}}">
```

`MenuList` is the property that returns the list of Dishes.

With `Source`, you tell XAML where to look for this property, this points to your Static class

Comment: Worked perfectly and thank you for explaining, this is the first time I've used either of these features in C#.